# Python Zip list to Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'd like zip some lists from html, I use codes like:

```
html_link = 'https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fpage_id=3261.html'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

search = re.compile(r"March.+2021")

for td in soup.find_all('td', text=search):
    link = td.parent.select_one("td > a")

    if link:
        titles = link.text
        links = f"Link : 'https://www.pds.com.ph/{link['href']}"
        dates = td.text
for link, title, date in zip(links, titles, dates):
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'col1':title,'col2':link,'col3':date},index=[0])
    print(dataframe)
```

But the output is not what I expected:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    P    L    M
  col1 col2 col3
1    D    i    a
...
```

What I EXPECT is:

```
Titles Links Dates
...    ...    ...
```

May I ask if the syntax is correct or what could I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create a dataframe from the extracted values then, you need to store them in list before performing `zip`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re

html_link = 'https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fpage_id=3261.html'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

search = re.compile(r"March.+2021")

titles = []  # to store extracted values in list
links = []
dates = []
for td in soup.find_all('td', text=search):
    link = td.parent.select_one("td > a")

    if link:
        titles.append(link.text)
        links.append(f"Link : 'https://www.pds.com.ph/{link['href']}")
        dates.append(td.text)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(zip(titles, links, dates), columns=['Titles', 'Links', 'Dates'])
# or you can use
# dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Titles': titles, 'Links': links, 'Dates': dates})


print(dataframe)

#                                              Titles                                               Links           Dates
# 0  RCBC Lists PHP 17.87257 Billion ASEAN Sustaina...  Link : 'https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fp=...  March 31, 2021
# 1  Aboitiz Power Corporation Raises 8 Billion Fix...  Link : 'https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fp=...  March 16, 2021
# 2  Century Properties Group, Inc Returns to PDEx ...  Link : 'https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fp=...   March 1, 2021
# 3  PDS Group Celebrates 2020’s Top Performers in ...  Link : 'https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fp=...  March 29, 2021
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help ,it works fine. may I ask why my code doesn't work, is it a must to create the empty list first?

Comment: @Joyce yes, because you are using a for loop to extract values from the source. When you do `titles = link.text` the values are getting overwritten. Once you exit the for loop, you will only have single row values. If you only need that value in the dataframe then you can use `dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Titles': titles, 'Links': links, 'Dates': dates}, index=[0])`. *Note: here titles, links and dates are not list*. Also strings are iterables, so when you zip string objects, it will get treated similar to a list. You can run `print(list(zip(titles, links, dates)))` see how it will look like.

Answer (score 3):

You can just pass the result from `zip` directly to `pd.DataFrame`, specifying the column names in a list:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(titles, links, dates), columns=['Titles', 'Links', 'Dates'])
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but the dataframe does not work out either like```Titles Links Dates
0       P     L     M
1       D     i     a
2       S     n     r
3             k     c
4       G           h
5       r     :      
6       o           2
7       u     '     9
8       p     h     ,
9             t      
10      C     t     2
11      e     p     0
12      l     s     2
13      e     :     1```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say? If you don't want an index column you could use one of the other columns as the index e.g. `df.set_index('Titles')`

Comment: Or are you trying to get all the titles, links and dates in one row? If you could edit your question to show exactly what the expected output is for that sample data it would be easier to give you what you need.